# google spanner close connection

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner, gcloud-node

I running my api based on swagger and node.

When my api is running for few minutes without a request and then i send an api request to it, I got this error:

```
{ Error: {"created":"@1488097564.272436000","description":"Delayed close due to in-progress write","file":"../src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.c","file_line":406,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1488097564.272434000","description":"Endpoint read failed","file":"../src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.c","file_line":1851,"occurred_during_write":1,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1488097564.272350000","description":"Secure read failed","file":"../src/core/lib/security/transport/secure_endpoint.c","file_line":166,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1488097564.272347000","description":"Socket closed","fd":24,"file":"../src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.c","file_line":249,"target_address":"ipv4:172.217.19.10:443"}]}]}]}
    at ClientReadableStream._emitStatusIfDone (/Users/aronsuarez/Code/asate/admin-apis/wiki-admin-api/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:201:19)
    at ClientReadableStream._readsDone (/Users/aronsuarez/Code/asate/admin-apis/wiki-admin-api/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:169:8)
    at readCallback (/Users/aronsuarez/Code/asate/admin-apis/wiki-admin-api/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:242:12) code: 14, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } }
```

I think google spanner is closing the connection, why and how can prevent it from to that?

The only way that i see in the docs is to send periodically a `SELECT 1` request to spanner.

Is this correct?

Thanks for help

Comment: To clarify, are you using the official [gcloud Node library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gcloud), or something else?

Comment: I use the official gcloud node library - latest version